# transaction processor function for REST API post

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

My problem is that I want to implement some logic on the creation of an asset. There are already default REST API post transactions for creating assets. However I don't know if it is possible to create transaction processor functions for them.

My work around is to create my bespoke transactions in the model file which mimic these default post functions. These bespoke transactions can then have transaction processor functions can implement my desired logic.

I feel this is an ugly solution though - I have to feed all parameters into a transaction which in turn feeds it into an asset - and introduces other problems with duplication and using the wrong transaction

Is there a way I can implement my logic directly into the POST functions ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The default POST requests for Assets and Participants use "system" transactions:

`org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant` and `org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset`

I doubt that you can change them but there is a document in the Composer docs for [customising the REST server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/customizing-the-rest-server) which is worth checking out.

Comment: thanks a lot , this was exactly what I was looking for - turns out you can change them ! Thanks again